# Do the texture coordinates go through the various Shader pipeline?

Tags: c++, opengl

If I have this code:

```
const char* vertex_shader =
      "#version 400\n"
      "layout(location =  0) in vec2 vp;"
      "layout(location = 1) in vec2 tex;"
      "out vec2 texCoord;"
      "void main () {"
      "  gl_Position = vec4 (vp, 0.0f, 1.0f);"
      "  texCoord = tex; "
      "}";

   const char* fragment_shader =
      "#version 400\n"
      "uniform sampler2D s;"
      "in vec2 texCoord;"
      "out vec4 color;"
      "void main () {"
      "color = texture(s, texCoord);"
      "}";
```

What I would like to know is that based on what I understand, the vertices given to vertex shader, once it passes the vertex shader it goes to [Rasterization which is](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Rasterization)

> Rasterization is the process whereby each individual Primitive is
>   broken down into discrete elements based on the sample coverage of the
>   primitive.

Since the actual tex-coordinates is given as a primitive with vertices, does it also get broken down after being transformed to the various spaces, in order to generate al the fragments that fall within its range?

And if they don't, then how does the fragment shader get the data where to put them on the actual rendered primitive?

Please also if your going to answer this question with mathematics, bear in mind I am a beginner and you will need to explain it thoroughly

So far what I have seen explaining this process I have not understood due to all the matrices talk, which I am not even sure covers the question I am asking about

I do understand matrices and vectors, but very basic level so keep all maths talk basic and explained, none of that intuitive knowledge cause I don't have it yet

Answer (score 2):

Rasterization only happens once for each triangle. So if you're wondering if the texture coordinates are rasterized just like the positions, the answer is: No.

The process you're looking at, which is part of the fixed function block that is executed between vertex and fragment shader, consists of two main steps:

1. Fragments are **generated**. This step enumerates all fragments that are inside each triangle, based purely on the `gl_Position` value that you produced as output of your vertex shader (*) for each of the 3 triangle vertices.
2. Vertex shader outputs are **interpolated**, meaning that a value for each output is calculated for each fragment generated in step 1. This takes the output at each of the 3 triangle vertices (which your vertex shader produced), and then interpolates those values across the triangle to calculate a value for each fragment.

The calculation of the interpolated values happens in barycentric coordinates, meaning that the barycentric coordinates of each fragment within the triangle are calculated, and then the vertex values are interpolated linearly to get the value for the fragment at those barycentric coordinates.

The interpolated vertex shader output values resulting from this are then used as the values for the corresponding fragment shader input. So when the fragment shader is invoked for each of the fragments generated in step 1, the interpolated values calculated in step 2 become the inputs for the fragment shader.

In summary, only the `gl_Position` output of the vertex shader is used to generate fragments, but all outputs (which are the position and texture coordinates in your example) are interpolated.

This special role of `gl_Position` also explains why it's still a predefined variable in the OpenGL core profile, while most of the other predefined variables that used to be present in older versions of OpenGL have been removed.

(*) There is additional processing that is applied to the `gl_Position` value before it gets to this stage, like perspective division and clipping.

Comment: would you be able to explain this interpolation process a bit more in basic terms for 2d plane? the reason i want to know is so that i can write better accustomed code for when i am drawing to the screen, because knowing how it works will accommodate better useful code , so far i only have conjecture, and in my code i can play with what i give as texture coordinates to an obvious face like a 2d polygon, but i would like to know more about it so that if i have to work with something awkward like an triangle primitive for square image, then i can apply the textures appropriately etc

Comment: can you for example help me understand by explaining how a 2*2 pixel texture gets on the screen from vertex shader to fragment shader and then onto a 2*2 size polygon, using direct example of how it happens in opengl ? this would help me understand this process if you can?

Comment: i appreciate your answer, but what i am looking for is HOW this process happens , that's the important part , how does the fragment shader decide which texture data to use,  how does the rasterization/fragment shader choose which part of the buffer to use of the texture coordinates, and why does it even need the UV vertices and how to use them, advance to the next part , how does it divide up the screen or area to which you are rendering , whether it be scaled down or up and what does it do with and how does it use it, where does it determine it and when does it determine it?

Comment: I added a paragraph with more details on how the interpolation is performed. Beyond that, it sounds like you're looking for much more than what can reasonably be covered in a few paragraphs. The latest OpenGL specs are about 1000 pages, and that does not cover computer graphics basics. So I don't think it's reasonable to expect coverage of various basic graphics concepts, the whole rendering pipeline, and details of each step, in one answer here.

Comment: @hopjopper: That question is far too broad for Stack Overflow. What you're talking about would be an entire chapter of a graphics textbook.

Comment: fair enough, then can you suggest where i can find this information? which books and what chapters or which websites and tutorials to read which explains these things in details ?

Comment: @RetoKoradi why are the fragment that are generated from step one interpolated further? it doesnt make sense to me? if you have all the fragments as window coordinates why do you need to further interpolate them? i can understand why you would do it if you needed to find the points in the triangle, but if you already have the points/fragment why does it happen again? Also why does a value need to be calculated for each fragment? isnt a fragment already in window coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

> Since the actual tex-coordinates is given as a primitive with vertices, does it also get broken down after being transformed to the various spaces , in order to generate al the fragments that fall within its range?

Yes. For a simple reason:

The numbers that are passed to the drawing process are in the first stage without meaning. It's the vertex shader's task to take the vertex attributes, which are just some numbers and to give them semantics for the next stage (as far as the metal is concerned, semantics just means, values at locations in memory are passed into a (logical) register location for consumption of the next stage). What's the position is transformed into the place on where the vertex shall appear at the screen (assignment to `gl_Position`). Other attributes' values can either be discarded, used to control the position determination or be passed on to the next state.

When it comes to the pass between vertex transform and fragment stage it is specified that the output values are interpolated* between the screen positions before passed into the fragment stage. This interpolation is, what you referred to as "get broken down".

---

*: Interpolation can also mean: Constant value interpolation from the first vertex in the primitive, i.e. flat shading.